# How get a field dynamically in xml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

```
       $xml=' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <cardNumber>4444333322221111</cardNumber>' // here how to pass a 
                        value dynamically fro sale order payment table
```

what is the format of get a value dynamically in xml field in controller file

Comment: dynamic from where? what XML file?

Comment: I want to get a dynamic value from sales_order_payment table xml fields are placed within my controller file

Comment: As a new user, i can understand your difficulties in illustrating the task that you struck with. But the only way you can get right pointers even a solution is by elaborating your requirement, what have you tried so far and what did you struck with ?  Based on what have you mentioned there, i understand that you want to retrieve the customer-sensitive payment information  from sales_order_payment table and generate a XML to send it back to your payment provider / or to your CRM / ERP. but you got struck with retrieving the value. Is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically pass a value by

```
  <cardNumber>'.$cardnumber.'</cardNumber>
```